# Paypal Checkout - What do I use to checkout and save to db, express/ipn? php

Tags: php, paypal

I do not have a cart. I want users to choose between a few prices (eg$5, $10 or $20) and then add that amount to their account in a database after transaction. I already have a Paypal account, and that's about as far as I've got. I thought paypals developer section would guide me through like I was a 5 year old, but i'm lost. I've always simply used the paypal html code with a button that has a set amount, and then after checkout sends the user back to my site with a variable in the URL that has the payment amount to log the amount to a database. Very bad I know seeing as users could simply change the url if they knew, I am attempting a better method. A lot of searching led me to IPN. I have enabled IPN to my account and setup a url for the listener. My question now is what is the best method to use for my checkout? Is the Express checkout what I need, or Classic API? What triggers the ipn message?
 Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once IPN is configured on your PayPal account the IPN's will be triggered any time an actual transaction takes place.  This includes payments, refunds, disputes, updates on pending payments, etc.

As for the handling of the actual payment, you could still use standard buttons, or you could use the Express Checkout API (which is part of the Classic API), or any other number of payment integrations that PayPal offers.

If you're comfortable with PHP and web services I'd recommend going with the [Express Checkout API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/).  You can use my [PHP class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/product/php-class-library-paypal/) to make this very simple for you.  It'll involve the following API calls.

- [SetExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/)
- [GetExpressCheckoutDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_NVP/)
- [DoExpressCheckoutPayment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_NVP/)

The IPN would be triggered as soon as the DECP request is completed.

Comment: Thanks Andrew Angell, Is it correct that express checkout doesn't accept credit cards just paypal? Would I have to use paypal payment pro to accept credit cards?

Comment: You can use Express Checkout for credit cards.  Payers can go through "guest checkout" and they don't need to login or create a PayPal account.  If you set SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole, LANDINGPAGE=Billing, and USERSELECTEDFUNDINGSOURCE=CreditCard in your SetExpressCheckout request it'll make it more obvious to people they can pay that way.